# Line feeder in unwanted places causing problem in reading data

Tags: notepad++

My data has over 50,000+ observations. The problem is line feeder `LF` is inserted all over the place causing import into statistical software like STATA a nightmare. I have tried many different options in STATA and finally given up on STATA. Now, after spending half a day in Notepad++, I found out that manually deleting "LF" wherever the data is pushed into a new row fixes the problem.

I tried using 'replace all' 'LF' with nothing(empty cell) but it results in all data clumping in one single line (softwares(Excel, STATA) interprets this as a lengthy variables list).

I am hoping someone might have encountered issues like this and have found a solution. If anyone could share those solutions it would be awesome!

Messy data in notepad++ displays as:

```
"id"|"sex"|"choice"LF
"1aef2"|"M"|"burger",.LF
"pizza"LF
"pasta"LF
"B2qwX"|"F"|"salad".LF
"keto diet",LF
""LF
```

I want a clean data as:

```
"id"|"sex"|"choice"LF
"1aef2"|"M"|"burger","pizza""pasta"LF
"B2qwX"|"F"|"salad""keto diet",""LF
```

Please help!

Comment: How can you tell which lines have data pushed into the next row? Is the line with no `|` belongs to the line above it?

Comment: Based on variable names and ids are always alpha-numeric.

Comment: Some programming might be needed. What programming languages do you have available on your computer? VBA, Python, PHP, something else?

Comment: I have R, STATA, Python

Comment: I've added an answer with VBA and Python code. It's tested on a small example. You will have to adapt the code to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove linefeed when the next line doesn't contain a pipe character.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\n(?!.*\|)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\n          # linefeed
(?!         # negative lookahead, make we haven't, after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    \|          # a pipe character
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Excel, Word or other Office products on your computer, use the method below (since I have the code written for that; I'll write Python at the tail end in a bit).

- Open Excel
- Use this video to add Developer workbook: https://youtu.be/_oZGdg1aiEQ?t=26
- Go to Developer tab and click Visual Basic

Add a Module by right clicking on VBA Project > Insert > Module

[image]

Go to Tools > References > check Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Then, in the white space you can paste the code below:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CorrectFileFormat()

    Dim InFile As FileSystemObject
    Set InFile = New FileSystemObject
    
    Dim OutFile As FileSystemObject
    Set OutFile = New FileSystemObject
    
    Dim InFilePath As String
    InFilePath = "c:\test.txt"
    
    Dim OutFilePath As String
    OutFilePath = "c:\test2.txt"
    
    Dim InStream As TextStream
    Set InStream = InFile.OpenTextFile(InFilePath, ForReading, False)
    
    Dim OutStream As TextStream
    Set OutStream = InFile.OpenTextFile(OutFilePath, ForWriting, True)

    Dim Line As String
    Dim OutputLine As String
    OutputLine = ""
    
    Dim LineNo As Integer
    LineNo = 1
    
    While Not InStream.AtEndOfStream
LoopStart:
        Line = InStream.ReadLine
        
        ' if line is empty, skip it
        If Len(Trim(Line)) = 0 Then
            GoTo LoopStart
        End If
        
        ' write the header line to the output file as-is
        If InStr(Line, """id""|") = 1 Then
            OutStream.WriteLine (Line)
            GoTo LoopStart
        End If
        
        ' if line contains a separator, we should store this line in
        ' outputline buffer. Before doing that, check if outputline has information in
        ' it. If it does, write it to the file first and then overwrite
        ' its contents
        If InStr(Line, "|") > 0 Then
            If Len(Trim(OutputLine)) > 0 Then
                OutStream.WriteLine (OutputLine)
            End If
            OutputLine = Line
            
        Else
            OutputLine = OutputLine + Line
        End If
        
        LineNo = LineNo + 1
    Wend
    
    ' write whatever's in outputline to the output file
    OutStream.WriteLine (OutputLine)
    
    InStream.Close
    OutStream.Close
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```

Put your cursor anywhere inside the subroutine and click on the run button.

[image]

You will see a message box `Done`.

Original text file

```
"id"|"sex"|"choice"
"1aef2"|"M"|"burger"
"pizza"
"pasta"
"B2qwX"|"F"|"salad"
"keto diet",
""
```

[image]

New text file

```
"id"|"sex"|"choice"
"1aef2"|"M"|"burger""pizza""pasta"
"B2qwX"|"F"|"salad""keto diet",""
```

[image]

You can adapt the code to your requirements.

## Python example

```py
inpath = r'c:\test.txt'
outpath = r'c:\test2.txt'

infile = open(inpath, 'r')
outfile = open(outpath, 'w')

indata = infile.readlines()

outstring = ''

for line in indata:
    
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        continue
    
    if line.startswith('"id"|'):
        outfile.write(line)
        continue
        
    if '|' in line:
        if len(outstring) > 0:
            outfile.write(outstring + '\n')
        
        outstring = line.strip()
    
    else:
        outstring += line.strip()
    
outfile.write(outstring + '\n')

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Adapt this code to your needs.